# Python multiplayer game with websockets: Handling multiple clients

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, async-await, multiplayer

I'm trying to build a multiplayer game (to be precise a Card game) in Python via **websockets**, but I'm currently failing in the very early steps.

**What I'm trying to do:**

- Clients connect to the websocket, until a certain number is reached
- The client sends an input to the server
- The server responds to each client separately and simultaneously

**What works:**

- Letting the client connect and storing a websocket per client works as expected, but then I'm a bit stuck.

What I've tried:

**client.py**

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import random


def random_name():
    return "".join([random.choice("abcdefghijkl") for _ in range(5)])


async def main():
    uri = "ws://localhost:1235"
    print("Starting...")
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:
        client_name = random_name()
        await ws.send(client_name)
        print(await ws.recv())  # server sends :client_name registered
        print(await ws.recv())  # server sends: 3 people registered
        print(await ws.recv())  # server sends: Waiting for input
        inp = input()
        await ws.send(inp)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**server.py (very naive approach)**

```
import websockets
import asyncio

clients = []


async def main(ws, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        print(f"Waiting for new connection! {ws}")
        client_name = await ws.recv()
        clients.append((client_name, ws, ws.remote_address))
        await ws.send(f"{client_name} registered on {ws.remote_address}")

        if len(clients) >= 3:
            registered_clients = ', '.join([c[0] for c in clients])
            print(f"3 clients ({registered_clients}) registered")
            break

    for name, ws_, _ in clients:
        await ws_.send(f"3 clients registered ({registered_clients})")
        await ws_.send(f"Waiting for input")

    for _ in clients:
        inp = await ws_.recv()
        print(ws_.remote_address, inp)


start_server = websockets.serve(main, "localhost", "1235")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

This fails with `RuntimeError: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message`. It seems that I cannot wait for the answer of each connected clients individually. Even though not perfect, I thought I can distinguish each client by looking at their remote addresses. For doing so, I modified the main function to

**server.py, main function (naive approach)**

```
async def main(ws, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        print(f"Waiting for new connection! {ws}")
        client_name = await ws.recv()
        clients.append((client_name, ws, ws.remote_address))
        await ws.send(f"{client_name} registered on {ws.remote_address}")

        if len(clients) >= 3:
            registered_clients = ', '.join([c[0] for c in clients])
            print(f"3 clients ({registered_clients}) registered")
            break

    for name, ws_ in clients:
        await ws_.send(f"3 clients registered ({registered_clients})")
        await ws_.send(f"Waiting for input")

    for _ in range(len(clients)):
        inp = await ws.recv()
        print(ws.remote_address, inp)
```

This doesn't work neither, cause the loop doesn't break for all connected clients.

My questions:

- How can my examples be repaired?
- Is the `websockets` package the right framework for me? Two things let me think of that:

  - In case of sockets, I can bind one client to the socket instance and directly read from one instance (which it seems I cannot easily do here).
  - Even though I'm pretty sure, that one can achieve what I want, it seems that there's a lot code involved for doing that (!?)
- But somehow I'd like to stick to websockets in general (because of also having the possibility to connect to communicate wit a browser). And sticking to the `websockets` package in particular, would have the advantage for me to get to know the `asyncio` module better. But if someone says, that I should rather switch to `aiohttp`, `flask-sockets`, `tornado` etc. I'd like to do so as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try to solved using a single transaction ID on the client side? Letting the server "publish" to all clients but clients would "consume" only message from server using their ID?